# product grid column filter not working in magento

Tags: magento, count, configurable

I am going to display only configurable products in my grid. and added one column to display number of simple configurable products under this product. for this i wrote like this. it is working fine. displaying number of simple products of configurable in columns. but how to apply column filter to this. it is not working. here is my query

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
             array('a'=>'catalog_product_super_link'),
                    'a.parent_id = e.entity_id',
       array('assoc_count'=>'count(a.parent_id)'))->group('e.entity_id');
```

displaying column here

```
    $this->addColumn('assoc_count',array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Count SimplePro'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'index' => 'assoc_count',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use filter_condition_callback

```
$this->addColumn('assoc_count',array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Count SimplePro'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'index' => 'assoc_count',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'assocFilterCallback'),
));

protected function assocFilterCallback($collection, $column) {
    $val = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    if (is_null(@$val))
        return;
    $collection->getSelect()->having('assoc_count=?', $val);
}
```

May be code should be rebuild, but I think you understand the idea.

Comment: thanks for your reply. just now i checked total grid filters not working. actually what i did means create a module and placed a product grid in 'core' to 'local' folder. here i am facing filter problem